# ASP.NET MVC ValidationAttribute causes invalid client side validation rules

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

I’m working on a ASP.NET MVC 5 Application. I’m using Attributes to validate my models (back- and frontend).

One of my models has a property which looks like this:

```
[Required( ... )]
[Range( 0d, Double.MaxValue, ...)]
public Decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

All values from **0** to **Double.MaxValue** are allowed as amount. (This works perfectly in the backend)

In my UI I have a form for this model:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @* Anti Forgery Token *@
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <fieldset>
        ...
        <section>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount, new { @class = "label" })
            <label class="input">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = Resources.Amount } })
                @Html.RenderCombinedValidationMessages(x => x.Amount, false)
            </label>
        </section>
    </fieldset>
    @Html.RenderGlobalValidationMessages()
    <footer>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="@Html.GetPreviousPage( Url.Action( "Index", "Controller" ) )" class="btn btn-default">@Resources.Back</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">@Resources.Create</button>
        </div>
    </footer>
}
```

This code creates HTML which looks like this:

```
<form action="/Controller/Create" class="smart-form" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    <fieldset>                                               
        <section>
            <label class="label" for="Amount">Amount</label>
            <label class="input">
                <input 
                    data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Amount must be a number." 
                    data-val-range="Amount must be between 0 and 1.79769313486232E+308." 
                    data-val-range-max="1.79769313486232E+308" 
                    data-val-range-min="0" 
                    data-val-required="Amount is required."
                    id="Amount" name="Amount" placeholder="Amount" type="text" value="">                
                <ul class="validationMessageList" data-property-name="Amount"></ul><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Amount" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </label>
        </section>
    </fieldset>
    <footer>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="http://localhost:26165/Controller/Create" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </div>
    </footer>
</form>
```

Now the problem:

Based on the validation attributes the HtmlHelper creates a jQuery validation rule for max range: **data-val-range-max="1.79769313486232E+308"**. This causes jQuery validate to allow only values from 0 to 1.79…. (values smaller than 2)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that i know is this:

```
      [Range(typeof(decimal), "0", "79228162514264337593543950335")]
      public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

Meh-ish, but this is a real deal.

And decimal MaxValue is 79228162514264337593543950335. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Bro' this will work. decimal is between -79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335 and 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335. You want > 0 values. This will work. 1000%

Comment: That's why i commented there about decimal MaxValue. What Double.MaxValue has to do with what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry you're right. I tested it again and it worked… (I made a stupid mistake in my previous test i used d(Double) instead of M(Decimal) … which resulted in an overflow exception)

Comment: Great. If you have any more questions, please update your requirements.